# Flutter: Til one side of a card-listtyle

Tags: flutter, shapes

Hy,

I am looking for a way to tilt one side a certain degree on a card-listtyle.
Basicly im trying to replicate this shape:

[image]

I have no clue to achieve this....

Comment: Tried to use you're example, but ShapeBuilder is giving issues so cant test :-(

Comment: Let me rephrase that... im having issues :-) But got it! Indeed what i was looking for! Thanks! Now to figure out how to mirror the same but on the left side (flipped horizontally)

Comment: Im terrible at math tho.... :-)

Comment: So in short: Works! My next step is to have 4 "versions" , angled on left or right side and from top to bottom, or bottom to top. So i can define on what side and direction the tilted side has to be for each card. As said i suck at math...Maybe you can hit me up in some DM like Telegram?

Comment: so your 4 "versions" should be unified into one generic version where you define 4 "center" points for each corner (used by 4 `arcTo` methods) - but yes it needs some math ;-)

Comment: Or an "easy" way to flip or rotate, without affecting the children like tekst etc, so only the shape. Else my tekst etc also gets flipped :-)

Comment: ask uncle google for `polygon rounded corners` - he answers with a lot of useful stuff ;-)

Comment: I did, formula's is math to ey ;-) Im having troubles getting the relationship between the numers and the effect it has. Thats  my problem tho. However, If you could do me one big favor in changing your first code so that the angled side is the other way around (Top wide, bottom small) would be much apriciated.

Comment: *"Top wide, bottom small"* - use angle > 90 degrees then - i think it should just work

Comment: you would only need to adjust `final r = ...` so that the shape fits the original `Rect rect`

Comment: That indeed did the trick, thank man, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: just one `if` but it could be done in more elegant way i think: `var r = rect.deflate(radius);
final dx = r.height / tan(angle);
if (angle > pi / 2) r = EdgeInsets.only(right: -dx).deflateRect(r);
...`

Comment: Using angle 1.2 did indeed flip the angle, but now the shape is extending outwards (as expected) since the anchorpoint is still bottomright (i guess). I think thats what you mean with final r = ... but puzzled how or what to change

Comment: the answer is one comment above yours

Comment: Tried that...but not sure where or what to change...

Comment: Got it! Works like a charm! Now you only have to change the degree from 0.8 to 1.2 to switch. Again, thanks for your help and patience ;-)

Comment: more elegant solution: https://gist.github.com/pskink/41bbb30e1d06de078bf59a10341ac29c#file-shape_builder-dart-L19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output

[image]

hope it will satisfy you. if you want to change some follow this : [modifyCorner](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/blob/master/lib/Utils/containerAdvanceCorner.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class COntainerStyle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _COntainerStyleState createState() => _COntainerStyleState();
}

class _COntainerStyleState extends State<COntainerStyle> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final boxWidth = 300.0;
    final boxHeight = 200.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: boxWidth,
            height: boxHeight,

            ///* second color
            color: Colors.blue.shade300,
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: -boxWidth * .7,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: .7,
                    child: Container(
                      ///* 2nd color of border
                      color: Colors.orange.shade800,
                      height: boxHeight * 1.2,
                      width: boxWidth * 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                //main view
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: boxWidth * .9,
                    height: boxHeight * .9,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(
                          12,
                        ),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
                          12,
                        ),
                        topRight: Radius.elliptical(
                          ///your x= .15 y: .82
                          boxWidth * .15,
                          boxHeight * .82,
                          // boxWidth * sliderValTX,
                          // boxHeight * sliderValTY,
                        ),
                        bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(
                          //Bx .13, by = .11

                          boxWidth * .13,
                          boxHeight * .11,
                          // boxWidth * sliderValBX,
                          // boxHeight * sliderValBY,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats actualy very close, thanks! No need for the blue and orange background tho, the OC was pure about the "white" card ;-).  The angled side is slightly round now, any way to make that straight? But again, thanks, this will srely help!